# Replace from start to end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've moved all images from my site into a different directory and so I need to update all old image sources, I'm not great with SQL so I'm struggling with where to start and how to tackle the situation.

Suppose I have a string defined like so:

```
DECLARE @Img VARCHAR(50) = '<img alt="" src="www.cars.com/Images/Cars/AudiA1.png" /> <img alt="" src="www.bikes.com/Images/Bikes/CBR.png" />'
```

I need a way to remove everything within the `src` attribute til `/Images/` meaning the end string should look like

`<img alt="" src="/Images/Cars/AudiA1.png" /> <img alt="" src="/Images/Bikes/CBR.png" />`

Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Was your question answered, @KTOV ?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the REPLACE() function.

You would use something like

```
SELECT @Img = REPLACE(@Img, 'www.cars.com', '');
```

Basically, what this is doing is replacing all instances of the string 'www.cars.com' found in the source (@Img in this case), with the empty string. This eliminates that string, resulting in just "/Images/Cars/AudiaA1.png", for example. Of course, if you have instances of that search string outside of your src and img tags, then you'll want to be more specific, like:

```
SELECT @Img = REPLACE(@Img, 'src="www.cars.com', 'src="');
```

This will only replace the src image tags, for example.